# How do game engines manage to 'detect' the opengl supported in a computer

Tags: opengl

I am learning OpenGL 3.3 and OpenGL 2.1. I want to make a game engine with both. So far I can do advanced stuff with both of them. I noticed that graphics engines like Irrlicht support OpenGL 1.x to 4.x. When i run an Irrlicht program in my computer that supports OpenGL 3.3, it runs perfectly. And when i run it in a computer with OpenGL 2.1, it still runs perfectly.

How does it *know* that my computer supports OpenGL 3.3, and adapt itself to it. Is it through trial and error? or how are they able to do this. That is a feature i want to incorporate in my game engine.

Comment: I think c/c++ projects can use [glew](http://glew.sourceforge.net/). Otherwise check for equivalents in your language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What works for me is simple:

```
// create OpenGL context first, gl** functions dont work without it

fOpenGL_Vendor   := String(glGetString(GL_VENDOR));
fOpenGL_Renderer := String(glGetString(GL_RENDERER));
fOpenGL_Version  := String(glGetString(GL_VERSION)); // <-- this
```

Last line returns OpenGL version reported by GPU driver, in a `x.x.x` format. You can trim last `.x` from it to get common 2-digit version format.

---

For example this is breakdown from my game:

```
Count   Version
2175    4.5
684     3.3
435     4.0
331     4.4
262     4.3
248     3.1
216     4.2
97      3.0
75      4.1
73      2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

The calls to glGetString don't always work without an existing opengl context.

One way to avoid creating a context to get the answers you are looking for
is to launch glinfo (or wglinfo.exe) , and read the text stream (or text file) to get your answer.

It may sound as an ugly method, but I remember working with cards that would simply crash for being asked to try a stereo mode. At least, when you launch an executable, you won't crash your application.

Comment: Does not glinfo creates a context of its own to query OpenGL caps?